# Finding a language for a NFSA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm having a bit of trouble determining what language the following non-deterministic finite state automaton accepts.

[image]

Assuming the alphabet of this machine is ${a, b}$, I deduced that this automaton would accept words of the following characteristic: a word $w$ would be accepted if $w$ had zero or more $a$'s or $b$'s followed by a single $a$ followed by zero or more $a$'s or $b$'s followed by a single $a$ followed by zero or more $a$'s and $b$'s.

Is there a more clear and concise explanation of what sorts of words are accepted by this automaton or would my explanation be suffice? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly identified your alphabet, but your verbal description is, indeed,complex.  Your NSA would accept any string with at least 2 `a`s.

There are many ways to describe NSAs. A regular expression or a regular grammar could be appropriate here. If this is for class, I would ask your professor what format he or she prefers.

Answer (score -1):

Let's trace it together:

- On `q1` state, you are looping on `a` or `b`, or you can proceed. That means `(a|b|E)*`, which can be simplified to `a*b*`.
- Then you move to `q2` on an `a`, which means `a*b*a`.
- Then on `q2`, it is the same as `q1`. Creating the expression `a*b*aa*b*`.
- Then transition on `a`: `a*b*aa*b*a`
- And looping on `a` or `b`: `a*b*aa*b*aa*b*`.

If your alphabet only contains `a` and `b`, then `a*b*` covers all combinations. The above expression can be comprehended as "`<anything>a<anything>a<anything>`", which can be verbally summarized as "strings that contain at least 2 occurrences of `a`".